# prevent OWLOntologyManager to go online

Tags: owl-api

Is there a way to configure owlapi to avoid fetching imports from the network? I have IRIMappers and I want everything to be local.

My symptom is that I'm missing import and I can't tell which one. If I'm not connected I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyInputSourceException: java.net.UnknownHostException: purl.obolibrary.org
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.getInputStream(DocumentSources.java:192)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrapInput(DocumentSources.java:121)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrapInputAsReader(DocumentSources.java:83)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.DocumentSources.wrapInputAsReader(DocumentSources.java:100)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.AbstractOWLParser.getInputSource(AbstractOWLParser.java:38)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:59)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:192)
    ... 7 more
```

Using 5.1.4

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AutoIRIMapper to point at a local folder containing a copy of the imported ontologies:

```
    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    PriorityCollection<OWLOntologyIRIMapper> iriMappers = m.getIRIMappers();
    iriMappers.add(new AutoIRIMapper(new File("materializedOntologies"), true));
```

You can also tell the manager to ignore import failures, but this will leave you with an incomplete ontology closure, meaning that reasoning will not be accurate.
This is achieved by setting the `org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.parameters.ConfigurationOptions.MISSING_IMPORT_HANDLING_STRATEGY`, which can be set as a system property or on the `OntologyConfigurator` object associated with the manager.

Comment: Setting the `MissingImportHandlingStrategy` to `SILENT` gets rid of the exception if offline but does not answer the question: How do I prevent owlapi to try to go online if an import is missing?

Comment: That's where the first part of my answer fits. Use AutoIRIMapper.

Comment: I do already but if the import isn't found in the folder then it will go online. I understand that having them all present avoids it but it's not enough.

Comment: You can use both: AutoIRIMapper /and/ set the missing imports strategy. The local imports will satisfy some requests and the requests that cannot be satisfied will be ignored.

Comment: That doesn't align with what I'm experiencing: if an import is missing it will be looked up online, I have an INFO log from `DocumentSources` confirming it. If that fails the missing import strategy will be used, but not before. I've tried with a `MissingImportListener` as well.

Comment: Is your use case to not have failures when not online? If so, it doesn't matter whether there is an attempt to download the import or not.

Comment: That was the symptom, which is indeed fixed by the `SILENT` strategy. My question is about controlling whether or not owlapi should go online, I don't want to risk having a different behavior depending on the connectivity.

Comment: You can use an IRIMapper that returns an empty ontology for each IRI received as input. That will stop all resolutions. However it's quite hard to see what you gain - what I'd do is load the ontology while online, make sure all imports are resolved, then save the imports closure locally. That way, I know all imports will be resolved from the local cache, until /I/ make changes to the imports of one of the ontologies. Behaviour will be consistent: all ontologies will be loaded from local storage.